# Upgrading to the latest Visual Basic in VS2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a VB.NET MVC project I developed in Visual Studio 2012 which I am now using in Visual Studio 2015.  I would like to start using things like null conditional operators.  But when I use one I get this compile error:

```
Visual Basic 12.0 does not support null conditional operations
```

How do I upgrade to the latest version of Visual Basic to be able to use such features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've upgraded to Visual Studio 2015, Update 1 (or higher?) and from the Project menu select "Enable C# 6 / VB 14"

In VS2017 the Project menu item is called "Enable latest C# and VB language features..."

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Visual Studio doesn't provide a straight forward way to customize the specific version of the VB.NET language.  By upgrading your IDE to 2015, the language version should automatically upgrade to the latest VB.NET.

However, it's possible that your .vbproj file has the language version hardcoded.

Try opening your .vbproj file in some editor, and look for something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>12</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you find this entry, remove it and save the project file.  Then try opening the project again and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry, but no such thing appears in the vbproj file